# PDF Generator using iText and java

Tags: java, ajax, pdf-generation, itext

I need to generate a PDF using iText, also using ajax to it. I have given a button, when on click, I have to get a pop-up for saving a pdf file as generally we get in many of the downloadable files. I;m not finding any wrong in the code please look into the code and help me. I have to print a simple table with rows and columns which i'm not able to.

**Ajax coding:**

```
function getFocusedPDF(){
    alert("Inside create PDF ajax");
    $.ajax({
        url : '/PreTestWeb/getFocusedPDF',
        type : 'get',
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json',

        success : function(map) {
            console.log(map);
        },

        error : function(map) {
            alert(map);
            alert("error occured!!!");
        },

    });


}
```

**Home Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFocusedPDF", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getRecentFocusGrpData(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    String contType="application/pdf";
    res.setContentType(contType);
    Gson json = new Gson();
    System.out.println("Inside home ctrlr");
    PdfGenerator pdf=new PdfGenerator();
    System.out.println("==== Before ===");

    byte[] b=pdf.createFirstTable();

    System.out.println("==== After ===");

    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=pdf.pdf");
    res.setContentLength(b.length);
    res.getOutputStream().write(b);
    res.getOutputStream().flush();
    res.getOutputStream().close();
     System.out.println("Last line in home ctrlr pdf generation");
}
```

**createFirstTable: (Method)**

```
public static byte[] createFirstTable() throws DocumentException, FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("=========Inside pdf generator ==========");
    // a table with three columns
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);       
    Document document=new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
    writer.setCloseStream(false);       
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);// new PdfTable(periodList.size() + 1);
    // the cell object
    PdfPCell cell  = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph ("Merry Moore"));
    cell.setColspan(2);
    table.addCell(cell);
    System.out.println("Added new paragraph");
    // now we add a cell with rowspan 2
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell with rowspan 2"));
    cell.setColspan(2);
    table.addCell(cell);
    System.out.println("Added new cell");
    // we add the four remaining cells with addCell()
    table.addCell("row 1; cell 1");
    table.addCell("row 1; cell 2");
    table.addCell("row 2; cell 1");
    table.addCell("row 2; cell 2");
    document.add(table);
    System.out.println("Added table to document");
    document.close();
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @ Klas: I neither get an error nor the pdf file.

Comment: Unrelated to the question: I find Jasper reports to be far superior and easier to use than piecing PDF reports together with iText. You should look into it.

Comment: I'm assuming you've already tried saving the PDF to the disk. And that it worked? Just making sure the error is on the download part.

Comment: @ Winzu: Saving is a problem here.. I'm not getting the pop-up to save or open the file...

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this with only an Ajax call.
Ajax can only receive responses in the form of text.

If you want to prompt a download, the way I do it is to fill a possibly hidden form and submit it via the ajax :

```
<form id="form" action="/downloadPDF.do" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="something">Something :</label> 
        <input type="text" name="something" id="something"/> 
    </fieldset>

$( "#button" ).click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#form').submit();
});
```

Comment: @ Winzu: I'm using a button for generating the pdf, as I have a report in the page wherein i give an option to view the report in pdf format. How will I go abt using .submit()???

Comment: Edited my answer, maybe it makes more sense now. You probably have an ID or something to identify your report. Set the input via javascript. Then you're just submitting a form.